# How to generate random json diffs in haskell quickcheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I need to test the framework that can observe the state of some json http resource (I'm simplifying a bit here) and can send information about its changes to message queue so that client of service based on this framework could reconstruct actual state without polling http resourse.

It's easy to formulate properties for such framework. Let say we have a list of triples `State, Diff, Timestamp`
`gen_states = [(gs1, Nothing, t1), (gs2, Just d1-2, t2), (gs3, Just d2-3, t3), (gs4, Just d3-4, t4)]`
and after mirroring all this state to the http resource (used as test double) we gathered `[rs1, rd1-2, rd2-3]` where `r` stands for received.

`apply [rd1-2, rd2-3] rs1 == gs4` final states should be the same the same

Also let's say that polling interval was more than the time difference between changes t3 - t2 than we can loose the diff `d2-3` but the state still have to be consisted with state that was at previous polling `gs2 for example`. So we can miss some changes, but the received state should be consisted with some of the previous states that was no later than one polling interval before.

The question is how to create a generator that generates random diffs for json resource, given that resource is always an array of objects that all have `id` key.

For example initial state could look like that

```
[
  {"id": "1", "some": {"complex": "value"}},
  {"id": "2", "other": {"simple": "value"}}
]
```

And the next state

```
[
  {"id": "1", "some": {"complex": "value"}},
  {"id": "3", "other": "simple_value"}
]
```

Which should make diff like

```
type Id = String
data Diff = Diff {removed :: [Id], added :: [(Id, JsonValue)]}

added = [aesonQQ| {"id": 3, "other": "simple_value"} |]
Diff [2] [added]
```

I've tried to derive `Arbitrary` for aeson `Object`, but got this

```
<interactive>:15:1: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        ‘arbitrary’
    • In the instance declaration for
        ‘Arbitrary
           (unordered-containers-0.2.8.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
              Data.Text.Internal.Text Value)’
```

But even if I would accomplished that how would I specify that `added` should have new unique id?

Comment: It would be helpful if you include some code, even if it represents a simplified version of your problem. It's difficult to tell what you're asking. Are you asking what a data type for a JSON diff should look like? Or something in particular about using quickcheck?

Comment: @jberryman I've edited the question. Not sure if it's helpful.

Comment: "I've tried to derive Arbitrary for aeson Object" - where is the code where you've done this? It looks like you've just written `instance Arbitrary Object` without defining any of the methods; this is wrong. You'll have to write an arbitrary instance yourself, but you shouldn't have an `instance Arbitrary Object` at all - just write a term `arbObject :: Gen Object` and use that term in the definition of your `instance Arbitrary Diff`

Comment: @user2407038 by deriving I meant standalone deriving.  Why do I have to write instance myself?

Comment: `Arbitrary` is not a derivable class so you can't typically use standalone deriving with it. If it has worked for you, it's because you're using `DeriveAnyClass`. That is exactly the same as writing `instance Arbitrary Object` without a class instance body. You have to write the instance yourself because you want the random values produce by arbitrary to have some property; the generic instance can produce any representable value.